# Encryption of data stored in Azure Tables (Azure Storage)

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have been facing issues with understanding what would be the best way to store encrypted data in Azure Tables. The main objective here is to avoid someone with access to database to be able to read that data on the storage explorer.

One approach I have looked at is encrypting it on our server logic before saving it to the db, but the solution is causing a performance hit on the application.

Is there a way to achieve this directly on the Azure Tables? If it isn't, what else would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Data in Azure Storage is encrypted at rest by default. The scenario you're describing probably fits best with this option:

> [...] create a storage account that relies on a key that is scoped to the account. When the account is first created, Microsoft uses the account key to encrypt the data in the account, and Microsoft manages the key. You can subsequently configure customer-managed keys for the account to take advantage of those benefits, including the ability to provide your own keys, update the key version, rotate the keys, and revoke access controls.
>
> Source: [Create an account that supports customer-managed keys for tables and queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/account-encryption-key-create?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2Ftoc.json&tabs=azure-cli)